# When do Rachni War Assets show up in game?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I completed Attican Traverse: Krogan Team and chose to save the Breeder. Yes, I know, terrible idea, she'll betray me later. I'm intentionally aiming for minimum possible war assets this time. According to what I've read on the Mass Effect Wiki, this should (temporarily) get me Rachni Workers and penalize Aralakh Company by 25 points. However, when I check the War Terminal I see Aralakh Company at its unmodified strength of 25 and no rachni.

Do these changes show up later? Does the Breeder not show anything until her betrayal? Have I encountered a bug? If it is a bug, could I use a save editor to fix it, and how?

Answer (score 1):

well if you saved queen in me1 and again in me3, she doesn't actually betray you.

She should send workers to the crucible project later; you get a message about it in the terminal.

Comment: I know the queen from the first game doesn't betray you. That's beside the point. I'm specifically asking about the Breeder, as part of intentionally tanking my war assets as much as possible.

I have finished this playthrough since posting the question, and all the way through Priority: Earth the only thing to come from saving her was gaining Aralakh Company.